# How does Gift of Immortality work with sacrificing its creature before a boardwipe?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What happens when you sacrifice a creature enchanted with [Gift of Immortality](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gift%20of%20Immortality) in response to a boardwipe?

Comment: Just to be clear: Do you sacrifice the creature before the board wipe resolves, or afterwards?

Comment: Either way I believe that you would lose the creature and the enchantment since Gift of Immortality has a delayed trigger to reattached to the creature.  The first effect would kill the creature while it is enchanted with Gift of Immortality and it would be brought back onto the field while the second effect would kill it while not enchanted and then Gift of Immortality would try to reattached at the end of the turn a fail and end up in the graveyard.

Comment: @Hackworth How could you sacrifice the creature after the board wipe resolves?

Comment: @GendoIkari "When enchanted creature dies, return that card to the battlefield under its owner's control." Then you sac it with the same unspecified outlet that would allow you to sac it beforehand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you sacrifice the enchanted creature in response to the board wipe (before it resolves), the creature dies and returns to the battlefield under its owner's control, while Gift of Immortality itself goes to the graveyard. The board wipe then resolves, killing the creature again, but this time without the enchantment, so the creature just goes to the graveyard as usual. When the end step arrives, Gift of Immortality tries to return to the battlefield attached to the creature, but since the creature is no longer on the battlefield, Gift of Immortality remains in the graveyard.